# Nix and Haskell-ng install error : attribute ‘nixpkgs’ in selection path ‘nixpkgs.haskellEnv’ not found

Tags: nix, haskell-ng

I am following [this](https://iilab.org/news/2015-03-27-nix-osx-haskellng-hakyll.html) guide to set up nix and haskell-ng. But when I get to the step

> nix-env -iA nixpkgs.haskellEnv

then I get the error:

> error: attribute ‘nixpkgs’ in selection path ‘nixpkgs.haskellEnv’ not
>   found

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I'm currently re-trying based on this: https://nixos.org/wiki/Nix_on_OS_X#Using_Nix_on_10.9_and_10.10, also maybe I made some simple mistakes.

Comment: OK, so it seems to work now.

Comment: It has been compiling stuff for 1 hour now, what is it doing so long and why?

Answer (score 10):

The command `nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -iA haskellEnv` should work.

Citing from http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure:

> Attribute paths are deterministic inside of Nixpkgs, but the path necessary to
>   reach Nixpkgs varies from system to system. We dodged that problem by giving
>   `nix-env` an explicit `-f "<nixpkgs>"` parameter, but if you call `nix-env`
>   without that flag, then chances are the invocation fails:
>
> ```
> $ nix-env -iA haskellPackages.cabal-install
> error: attribute ‘haskellPackages’ in selection path
>        ‘haskellPackages.cabal-install’ not found
> ```
>
> On NixOS, for example, Nixpkgs does *not* exist in the top-level namespace by
>   default. To figure out the proper attribute path, it's easiest to query for the
>   path of a well-known Nixpkgs package, i.e.:
>
> ```
> $ nix-env -qaP coreutils
> nixos.coreutils  coreutils-8.23
> ```
>
> If your system responds like that (most NixOS installations will), then the
>   attribute path to `haskellPackages` is `nixos.haskellPackages`. Thus, if you
>   want to use `nix-env` without giving an explicit `-f` flag, then that's the way
>   to do it:
>
> ```
> $ nix-env -qaP -A nixos.haskellPackages
> $ nix-env -iA nixos.haskellPackages.cabal-install
> ```